# Serialising slice object to JSON creates gibberish

Tags: json, go, slice

The following code serialises a Go slice into JSON:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type FooType uint8

const (
    Zero  FooType = 0
    One   FooType = 1
    Two   FooType = 2
    Three FooType = 3
)

func main() {
    var fooSlice []FooType
    fooSlice = make([]FooType, 1)
    fooSlice[0] = One
    bs, _ := json.Marshal(fooSlice)
    fmt.Println(string(bs))
}
```

Output:

```
"AQ=="
```

What I'm trying to achieve, and what I would expect to be printed is the following:

```
"[1]"
```

What is going on here?

Comment: See https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal, byte slices are base64 encoded

Comment: @JimB Wow, nifty feature actually. Cheers for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some simple examples:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   { // example 1
      b := new(strings.Builder)
      json.NewEncoder(b).Encode([]uint8{1})
      println(b.String() == "\"AQ==\"\n")
   }
   { // example 2
      b := new(strings.Builder)
      json.NewEncoder(b).Encode([]byte{1})
      println(b.String() == "\"AQ==\"\n")
   }
}
```

and the doc:

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that `[]byte` encodes as a
> base64-encoded string, and a `nil` slice encodes as the `null` JSON value.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json#Marshal